# Is there a way to know why guake crashes?

Tags: debian, guake

I looked at https://github.com/Guake/guake and there doesn't seem to be a way to troubleshoot why guake crashes. At times it would run for over 2-3 days and then suddenly it stops. Is there a way to know why it is crashing. If there is, please share with me.  The way guake is configured atm is that the moment a MATE session starts, guake starts and from it I spawn the browser and whatever other utilities I need. When it crashes other utilities break down.

Comment: What does `strace` or `sysdig` show it doing?

Comment: @thrig - I'll try it the next time it crashes, it simply would be ` $ strace guake` and $ sysdig guake` or how do I use that on another terminal ?

Comment: `strace -p $THE_PID_OF_GUAKE` possibly with some `-o` output file options, possibly with some `-ff` options. Also this will make guake hilariously slow, consider also `sysdig`.

Comment: @thrig, I haven't used strace so would this be correct `strace -p $PID_OF_GUAKE -ff -o guake-strace.txt` as an example of the command ? I looked at the manpage of sysdig too but wasn't able to figure out much.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach of running a program from CLI to see its output applies to guake too.

Kill your guake session, then simply start it again from a shell.

Comment: I have updated my query.